# english Vocabulary

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Many a time I experience problem in learning new words, like I learn and I know them but still whenever I have to write somewhere, I am using the same old words, is there a way to retain them easily?, like I have triend to learn from word roots but no results :(

Comment: There are many [mnemonic systems](http://www.mempowered.com/mnemonics/language/mnemonics-learning-languages) (commercial website link, but lots of free stuff, no affiliation to comment author) for approaching language learning, find what works for you .

Comment: Every time you learn a new word, write something using it.

Comment: What I used to do for my SAT, TOEFL, GMAT etc students was print around 10 words (from the weekly vocab)   to a page in large font, and paste them on a wall  wherever they might see them. Also, it takes a minimum of 5-7 uses of a word to make it stick in the memory, so you might want to try writing out 5 (correct) sentences using the new word. It might sound like an onerous task, but it works. // When I worked for the Korean Academy the daily requirement was 100 words a day, so as you can imagine the walls were _covered_...  and make sure you _say_ the words, not just read and highlight them.